# php regex filter phone numbers but not in link or image tags

Tags: php, regex, filter

I found this regex and it works perfectly for what i need EXCEPT it also is filtering 10 digit numbers inside of IMG tags and A HREF tags... I need to figure out how to make this replacement ignore 10 digit numbers inside a href and img src tags

`$string=preg_replace('/\(*\d{3}([().-\s[\]]*)\d{3}([().-\s[\]]*)\d{4}/','*****PHONE# HIDDEN*****',$string);`